# canvas drawimage issues, result in white , certain image only

Tags: canvas, drawimage

Trying to use canvas to drawImage.
if using this image result in white, if using others image, it work fine.
Please enlighten me. is there any
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TesBY.jpg (if you zoom in , it will appear the image...)

```
          const img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = reader.result;
          img.onload = () => {

            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = img.width
            canvas.height = img.height
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


            canvas.toBlob(resolve);
          };
        };
```

Comment: the image itself seems to be corrupted or use some not well supported features, as the original image appears white for me too once I change the zoom level in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

found a workaround, before process image to drawing,
perform a image conversion , guess it will repair the corrupted image...
i finally fix it this way.

import * as imageConversion from 'image-conversion';

```
   let compressIm = new Promise(resolve => {imageConversion.compress(imgObj,{
            quality: 1,
            type: "image/jpeg",
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            orientation:2,
            scale: 0.5,
          })
        })
```